# Generate number incremental, that works if you insert a custom row into the db

Tags: php, mysql

I am looking for some help with creating a function that generates an incremental number as a case id.

So, if a person creates a case, they get an incremental case number

I know how to do, but I need help with the scenario when the person creating a case, gives it a custom case id as an external reference, and then when creating the next case how do I generate the correct number incremental from the case before the custom one?

One of my thoughts was to create a file that contains the latest entered id, but I would think that there is a better solution to this issue.

EDIT/Additional information:
All cases created will have an auto incremented id by the database, but the case also has a case number which could be something like ZD-00009 and then increment to ZD-00010 and so on. But a case can also be created with a reference to something else outside of the company and in that scenario the case name/id could be DK51251 instead.

Comment: Have you tried anything

Comment: Isn't it better to just have the db tables primary (auto incremented) key as your case number and have another column for any potential reference id? Handling auto incremented numbers yourself is a bad idea and will end up biting you somewhere unpleasant.

Comment: let the database take care of the increment, just set the field as `AUTO_INCREMENT` https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/example-auto-increment.html

Comment: please don't use user intervention on id, just differentiate things, database id use incremental via mysql function and user id creates user itself. another solution could be for example (even if I do not recommend it) every time an ex id is created (the user enters 1) automatically before inserting extract the data and add 1 to the existing data.

Comment: Listen to @MagnusEriksson's suggestion. Modifying a user's input with typecasting is a risky path. You can end up with duplicate values. Split these IDs to your system IDs and reference IDs. Increment only those which under your full control (RDBMS will do it for you).

Answer (score 0):

> I am looking for some help with creating a function that generates an incremental number as a case id.

stop looking - it is MySql :)

> So, if a person creates a case, they get an incremental case number

this is

```
id int(11) unsigned not null auto_increment primary key
```

Don't touch the primary key, don't let anyone touch it

> scenario when the person creating a case, gives it a custom case id as an external reference ...

This has nothing to do with primary key, if is a need create columns `userId` and `reference` for `ZD-00009` and others - this columns should be only a number (foreign key) pointer to table of users or table of references - if they (users or reference id) are repeated.
User case identifiers do not need to have consecutive numbers increasing exactly by 1, they must be unique and increasing, this is all. If that's really not enough, add a timestamp to each case, but don't touch id's.